# Arithmetic problem for bicolored graphs

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-theory

A *bicolored graph* is a graph each vertex of which has been assigned one of two colors such that each edge connects vertices of different colors. A *bipartite graph* is a graph $G$ which admits such a coloring. Given $j$ white and $i$ black vertices, there are $2^{ji}$ ways to join vertices of different colors. Thus the number of (labeled) bicolored graphs on n vertices is
$$b_n=\sum_{i+j=n}\binom{n}i2^{ij}.$$

> **Question.** Is it true that $b_n$ is never divisible by $5$? If so, any proof?

**Update.** One combinatorial proof and two number-theoretic/algebraic proofs are supplied.

Comment: The pattern modulo $5$ appears to be $2,2,1,1$, repeating periodically.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This follows from the fact that for any prime $p$, and any integer $n\ge0$, we have  $b_{n+p}\equiv b_{n+1} \pmod p$. This can be proved by a straightforward, though not very interesting, computation, using Fermat's theorem $2^p\equiv 2 \pmod p$ and the fact that $\binom {n+p}{i} \equiv \binom ni + \binom n{i-p} \pmod p$.

More interesting is a combinatorial proof. (For similar proofs and further references,  see my paper [Combinatorial proofs of congruences](http://people.brandeis.edu/~gessel/homepage/papers/combinatorial-congruences.pdf), in *Enumeration and Design*, ed. David M. Jackson and Scott A. Vanstone, Academic Press, Toronto, 1984, pp. 157–197, especially section 5.)

We consider the cyclic group $C_p$ acting naturally on  $[p]=\{1,2,\dots, p\}$. This  extends to an action on bicolored graphs with vertex set $[n+p]=\{1,2,\dots, n+p\}$; the group permutes vertices $1, 2, \dots, p$, and does not change the other vertices. Since every orbit has size 1 or $p$, $b_{n+p}$ is congruent modulo $p$ to the number of bicolored graphs on $[n+p]$ fixed by this action of $C_p$. It is not hard to see that these fixed bicolored graphs are those in which all vertices in $[p]$ have the same color,  no edges join two vertices  in $[p]$, and all vertices in $[p]$ have the same neighborhood. By "contracting" all the vertices in $[p]$ to a single vertex, whose neighborhood is the same as the neighborhood of any of the vertices in $[p]$, we get a bicolored graph on $n+1$ vertices. Thus the number of fixed bicolored graphs is $b_{n+1}$, so $b_{n+p}\equiv b_{n+1}\pmod p$.

Answer (score 12):

For even $i$ we have $2^{ij}=2^{ni-i^2}\equiv 2^{ni}\pmod 5$  and $2^{ij}\equiv 2^{ni-1} \pmod 5$ for odd $i$. In other words, $2^{ij}\equiv \frac34 2^{ni}+\frac14 (-2^n)^i$. Thus $$\sum_i \binom{n}i 2^{i(n-i)}\equiv \frac34(1+2^n)^n+\frac14(1-2^n)^n\pmod 5,$$
this depends only on $n$ modulo 4 and we may easily consider all 4 cases.

Answer (score 12):

Here is an illustration of Ira Gessel's comment about a number-theoretic proof.

**Lemma.** *For $n\geq1$ and an odd prime $p$, the sequence $b_n$ mod $p$ is periodic of period $p-1$.*

**Proof.** Let $n=m(p-1)+r$, where $1\leq r\leq p-1$ and $m\geq0$. Proceed with a successive application of Fermat's, Lucas' and Chu-Vandermonde's theorems so that
\begin{align*}
b_n&=\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m(p-1)+r}{k(p-1)+j}2^{[k(p-1)+j][m(p-1)+r-k(p-1)-j]} \\
&\equiv_p\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m(p-1)+r}{k(p-1)+j}2^{j(r-j)} \\
&\equiv_p\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}2^{j(r-j)}\sum_{k\geq0}\binom{m}k\binom{r-m}{j-k}\\
&\equiv_p\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}2^{j(r-j)}\binom{r}j\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^r\binom{r}j2^{j(r-j)}=b_r.
\end{align*}
The proof is complete. $\square$

**Example.** The first 4 values of $b_n$ mod 5 are $[2,2,1,1]$, as Wojowu mentioned. By the Lemma, we conclude that $\nu_5(b_n)=0$, that is, $b_n$ is never divisible by $5$.